# Sort List<T> using string without Linq

Tags: c#, list, sorting, datatable

Is there a way to sort a `List<T>` using a string like `"Name desc"` (same as `DataTable.DefaultView.Sort`) rather then Linq?

I'm trying to replace `DataTables` with `Lists` and I need it to do this to be compatible with old code.

**SOLUTION**

using V4Vendetta's code I was able to create this extension method, tests seem to show it working.

```
public static void SortByString<T>(this List<T> list, string sortString)
{
    if (sortString == null) return;

    List<string> SortGroups = sortString.Split(',').ToList();

    for (int i = SortGroups.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)// sort from the last group first
    {
        string tempColumn = SortGroups[i].Trim().Split(' ')[0];
        bool isAsc = SortGroups[i].Trim().Split(' ').Length > 1 ? SortGroups[i].Trim().Split(' ')[1].ToLower() == "asc" ? true : false : true;

        PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(tempColumn);
        if (propInfo == null) // if null check to make sure its not just a casing issue.
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                if(pi.Name.ToLower() == tempColumn.ToLower())
                {
                    tempColumn = pi.Name;
                    propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(tempColumn);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (propInfo != null)
        {
            Comparison<T> compare = delegate(T a, T b)
            {
                object valueA = isAsc ? propInfo.GetValue(a, null) : propInfo.GetValue(b, null);
                object valueB = isAsc ? propInfo.GetValue(b, null) : propInfo.GetValue(a, null);

                return valueA is IComparable ? ((IComparable)valueA).CompareTo(valueB) : 0;
            };

            list.Sort(compare);
        }else{
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Property: '" + tempColumn + "', does not exist in '" + typeof(T).ToString() + "'");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had tried something on these lines maybe you need to improvise it a cit for your need

```
private List<Employee> CreateSortList<T>(
                    IEnumerable<Employee> dataSource,
                    string fieldName, SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        List<Employee> returnList = new List<Employee>();
        returnList.AddRange(dataSource);
        // get property from field name passed
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(fieldName);
        Comparison<Employee> compare = delegate(Employee a, Employee b)
        {
            bool asc = sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending;
            object valueA = asc ? propInfo.GetValue(a, null) : propInfo.GetValue(b, null);
            object valueB = asc ? propInfo.GetValue(b, null) : propInfo.GetValue(a, null);
            //comparing the items
            return valueA is IComparable ? ((IComparable)valueA).CompareTo(valueB) : 0;
        };
        returnList.Sort(compare);
        return returnList;
    }
```

You need to pass in the appropriate sort direction and the fieldname which would be property of the class (in my case Employee)

Hope this helps

Comment: @g.foley Did this help you out ?

Answer (score 3):

[List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) has some sort methods and some take a `Comparison<T>` that you can implement to have custom comparison an sorting

Comment: I tried this and learnt along the way. But was happier with the solution above, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in support for this type of search as far as I know. So you will have to write your own.

It should not be too hard to parse the string. Split it on commas (,) in case you have a sort string like "name asc, age desc" and treat each as a name and a direction. Then you can use reflection on the type T to find the property to sort on and build a method that performs the needed comparison.

Look at this article on codeplex for an example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/dynamite_dynamic_sorting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with the dynamic linq query library in the past: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: It's funny considering the bit about "without Linq" in the title of this question.

Comment: It's not uncommon for people to conflate LINQ with the strongly typed extension methods. The dynamic query library allows you to sort a list using a string instead, which might have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the specialized collections name space. There should be a sorted list in there.